# move_uploaded_file wont work on my local machine

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP area. This is my try to upload a file:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {

        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        if($file['error'] === 0) {
            $distination = 'uploads/';
            $file_ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename = $distination . uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
            if(!move_uploaded_file($file['name'], $filename)) {
                echo "File upload failed!";
            }
        }
    }
?>
<form action="testupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

the return value from the move_uploaded_file always `false`. I create  the uploads folder in the same directory as the upload script file.

Comment: The `uploads/` directory is likely not writable by the web server user. _Always_ develop code with error reporting turned up and displaying:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you'l  see the reasons for the failure.

Comment: Try adding $distination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';

Comment: ... it all depends on where 'uploads' is in the folder structure, but at very least I would expect it to be '/uploads/' or './uploads' and not just 'uploads/', and make sure 'uniqid' returns a value, not blank.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski where do I add error_reporting(E_ALL); & ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Add it to the top of your script, before any other PHP code.

Comment: I did it like so but nothing change. the only message I get is the echo message I wrote! "File upload failed!"

Comment: This is the uploads folder permission [drwxrwxrwx 2].

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is fact that you use `name` instead of `tmp_name` value from `$_FILES` array.

`name` is **original** name of uploaded file, `tmp_name` is location of file after upload. [Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Fixed version below. I also added check for destination directory and automatic creation of it if not available.

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {

        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        if($file['error'] === 0) {
            $distination = 'uploads/';
            if(!file_exists($distination)){
                mkdir($distination, 0777, true);
            }
            $file_ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename = $distination . uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
            print_r($file);
            if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
                echo "File upload failed!";
            }
        }
    }
?>
<form action="testupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```